# Username and Password not accepted in Swiftmailer to Gmail connection

Tags: swiftmailer

I've been using Swiftmailer to handle my app's email communication through to Gmail for some time now.

In the last 24 hours, a whole bunch of errors about the username and password not being accepted has popped up on the server log files.

From what I can understand, my options are to set up 2-step verification, or have an app specific password. Which is the right one for this type of scenario?

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls')
  ->setUsername($username)
  ->setPassword($password)
  ;
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject($subject);
$message->setFrom(array($from));
$message->setTo(array($to));
if(isset($cc) && $cc!="") $message->setCc(array($cc));
if(isset($bcc) && $bcc!="") $message->setBcc($bcc);
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the mail account has been deleted or deactivated?  That would be an obvious explanation ...

Comment: Hi Stephen. I'm logged into my gmail account in my browser, so it's definitely still there.